# Demonstrate that for a concave downward function that the value of the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is always higher than $\frac{y}{x}$

Tags: functional-analysis

I would like to demonstrate that for a concave downward function passing through the origin that the value of the derivative
$\frac{dy}{dx}$ is always higher than $\frac{y}{x}$. As shown in figure, it is simple to understand graphically, but for a generical concave downward function, without having a specific function, I don't know how to start.

Thank you in advance
[image]

Comment: the graph shows that the inequality is reversed

Comment: The thing you are trying to prove is not true

Comment: If you assume that the function passes through the origin then you should state so in the question.

Comment: Sorry @GCab I wrote it badly in the figure, Now I fixed it.

Comment: @dxiv sorry I forgot to mention it.

Comment: fixed ? actually the derivative is lower than the secant for the curve you show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use $$y=-(x-2)^2+C$$
Then at $x=1$ one gets $$\frac yx=C-1$$
and $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-2(1-2)=2$$
Notice that you can change the $y/x$ ratio to any number, while the derivative is always constant. So you can't prove that it is smaller or larger.

**EDIT** With the new addition to the question that the function passes through origin

The definition of concave function $f$ is that $\forall \lambda\in(0,1)$ $$f((1-\lambda)a+\lambda b)\ge(1-\lambda)f(a)+\lambda f(b)$$
So let's choose $a=0$ and $b=x$. We know that $f(0)=0$, so $$f(\lambda x)\ge\lambda f(x)$$
Then we want to calculate $$\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}h$$
We can choose $x-h=\lambda x$ or $h=(1-\lambda)x$.
$$\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}h=\frac{f(x)-f(\lambda x)}{(1-\lambda)x}\le\frac{f(x)-\lambda f(x)}{(1-\lambda)x}=\frac{f(x)}{x}$$

Comment: I forgot to say that the function should pass from the origin. I would like to do a generic demonstration

Comment: That's a very important missing part. I will add an edit to my answer

Comment: Thank you for your demonstration. I just want to ask you two questions. 1)Where in this demonstration, is pointed out the fact that the fucntion passes from the origin? 2) Since the derivative is a limit, the fact that you assume (1−λ)x tending to 0, do not affect the right member of the disequation? Sorry again

Comment: I used $f(0)=0$ to get from definition to the second equation in the edited part. If my final formula is true for every $\alpha$, it's true in the limit as well

Comment: which parameter is $\alpha$? This demonstration is true also if I choose different values of a and b?

Comment: Sorry, it's $\lambda$ not $\alpha$. In the last line I've used $f(\lambda x)\ge \lambda f(x)$. That came from $a=0$ and $b=x$. So the formula is valid only if the function passes through origin.